# loadHTMLFile from include() from ob_start include()

Tags: php, html, ob-start

My call chain is as follows: from b.php I need to place an image into, say a.php. So, I need to get its contents, do an XPATHsearch and so on. The file a.php is a short PHP script which roughly looks as follows:

### a.php

```
$var1="f1.html";
$var2="f2.html";
include(c.php)
```

c.php takes both f1 and f2, does loadHTMLFile on both of them, does certain modifications and then does saveHTML(). Without b.php, it works fine, and c.php returns html contents to the browser. However, at this point I need to call all this thing from b.php, and I cannot do this.
I've tried doing the following in b.php:

### b.php

```
ob_start();
include("a.php");
$file_content=ob_get_clean();
print_r($file_content);
```

But it doesn't work. It finds the a.php, but cannot load the html files and displays the following:
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "f1.html". It displays the same error for the second html file as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the content of the c.php file.

Comment: Ohh nevermind. It was the first time when I called the c.php from another folder, and that's why all the confusion. Thanks keupsonite.
Actually, as a follow-up question: should I always give absolute paths to include() to avoid these cases?

Comment: the better way for including is like that: `include_once(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'c.php');`